# Azure SQL Databricks Integration

Tags: sql-server, dataframe, jdbc, azure-sql-database, databricks

These are my JDBC connection details:

```
jdbcHostname = "ss-owaisde.database.windows.net"     
jdbcPort = 1433    
jdbcDatabase = "database-owaisde"     
jdbcUsername = "owaisde"             
jdbcPassword = "******"            
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     

jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName= 
{jdbcDatabase};user{jdbcUsername};password={jdbcPassword};driver={jdbcDriver}"
```

Executing the spark read

```
df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", 
"SalesLT.Product").load()
```

Getting the following error on databricks

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue with your code:
I got same error:

[image]

As per my knowledge in your case URL is not build in correct format. I tried with below code:

```
jdbcHostname = "<servername>.database.windows.net"     
jdbcPort = 1433    
jdbcDatabase = "<dbname>"     
jdbcUsername = "<username>"             
jdbcPassword = "<password>"            
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
 
#url = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${database_host}:${database_port}/${database_name}"
table = "Student"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"
```

[image]

```
df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbcDriver).option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", table).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()
```

Dataframe created successfully.

[image]

It worked fine for me, check from your end.